# Showing $\langle Ku,v\rangle=\langle u,K^*v\rangle$ for a Fredholm Operator $K$

Tags: integration, proof-verification, inner-products, adjoint-operators

> Consider a Fredholm operator $K$ define by $$Ku(x)=\int_{a}^{b} k(x,y)u(y) \ dy \ \ \ a\leq x\leq b,$$ where $k(x,y)$ is some known function of $x$ and $y$ called the kernel of $K$, and define the usual inner product $$\langle f,g \rangle=\int_{a}^{b} f(x)g(x) \ dx.$$ Te adjoint of $K$ is the integral operator $K^*$ define by $$K^*u(x)=\int_{a}^{b} k(y,x)u(y) \ dy \ \ \ \ a\leq x\leq b.$$
>   Show that $\langle Ku,v \rangle=\langle u,K^{*}v \rangle$ for any continuous function $u,v$.

My attempt:

Consider
\begin{align}
\langle Ku,v \rangle&=\int_{a}^{b} Ku(x)v(x) \ dx \\
&=\int_{a}^{b} \int_{a}^{b} k(x,y)u(y) v(x) \ dy \ dx  \\
\end{align}
But I am not certain on how to proceed, as I assume $k(x,y)\neq k(y,x)$.  A hint would be very helpful.

Comment: $\int_c^d$ should be $\int_a^b$. And why not compute $\langle u,K^*v\rangle$?

Comment: Okay, I will amend that now. I was trying to differentiate the limits of the two integrals, but I see that isn't in accordance with the information provided. And for the computation of $<u,K^*v>$, I run into the same problem of not being able to show that one side of the required result  equals the other.

Comment: In your double integral, let $x \to y, y \to x$.

Comment: Awesome. I have done this and it works. But it does not make intuitive sense to me. How did you know to do this? Are you able to explain a little.